# How does one clear the tesseract cache?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-cffi

I am using the `cffi` library with tesseract's C-interface.

My deletion pattern is:

```
if self.result_iterator != self.ffi.NULL and self.result_iterator is not None:
    self.TessResultIteratorDelete(self.result_iterator)

self.TessBaseAPIClearPersistentCache(self.agent)
self.TessBaseAPIClear(self.agent)
self.TessBaseAPIEnd(self.agent)
self.TessBaseAPIDelete(self.agent)
self.agent = None
```

I have thrown every delete method I can think of or find in the library at this.

However, my memory usage graph monotonically increases until OOM-killed when processing the same image over and over.

This happens whether or not I call the deletion method above.

[image: Memory Usage Pattern -- each bump is another recognition event]

---

My interpretation here is that `libtesseract` has some mystery cache that it keeps around to prevent re-processing.  The mystery cache is either not getting freed or not getting garbage collected.

Is there a way to release this cache that I am missing?

Comment: What happens if you remove these `try: except Exception`?

Comment: @ArminRigo Updated the delete procedure, memory leak remains :(

Comment: How did you measure memory use?  Maybe you can create C version that replicates the problem and post it to the tesseract issue tracker...